# Materialize Table Row Height Override?

Tags: html, css, html-table, row, materialize

I have a table that I'd like to override the row height of, as the rows are just too tall.  I tried setting a class on tr on my own css and setting the height value.

CSS: No seriously, that's all the css for this template. And html

```css
tr.unitGridRow {
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<tbody>
  {{#each unitInService}}
  <tr class="unitGridRow">
    <td>
      <div class="chip" style="background: {{unitColorCode}}; color: {{unitTextColorCode}};">
        {{callSign}}
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>{{currentStatus}}</td>
    <td>{{timeInStatus}}</td>
  </tr>
  {{/each}}
</tbody>
```

but the row height never changes.  I'm using Meteor 1.5.0 and Materialize 0.98.2 currently.

Any help is greatly appreciated,

Comment: We need to see more code (HTML and maybe CSS) to determine why your table rows are tall.

Comment: @JonUleis I have updated my code in the question.  Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

This might come too late, but may help for future googlers.

The row height is fixed because of the padding. Manually modify the padding in css, that should do the work. At least it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

The unit `vh` stands for 'viewport height', and the number represents a percentage of the viewport height.  So `1vh` means 1% of your window height.  Thats very small, and a table row doesn't want to be smaller than the height of its content.  Set this to `50vh` and see what happens.  Not sure what you are trying to achieve, but `vh` doesn't seem like the right unit for a row height.  If the rows are too tall, there must be something inside them making them tall.

Comment: yeah, sorry, I had just set that to see if it would change at all.  I tried 10 px, 20 px, 40 px, 100 px, and so on, and no matter what I change the height setting to, it doesn't budge at all.   I'll update the CSS in my question to avoid confusion on it.  I'm guessing it's something built into the Materialize library, but I haven't overcome it yet.  I also tried adjusting the padding-top and bottom, still no luck.

Comment: Use the inspector and go through all the styles for the contents of the row.  There is something inside it that is forcing its height.

Comment: The row appears to be locked to 68 pixels tall.  I have nothing in it but a chip (32 pixels) and text (much smaller).  All tables in Materialize have this style of row, I figured it wouldn't be so hard to override it, but I guess I'll have to override the whole table maybe.

Comment: Got it - the td height also had to be adjusted...ugh!  Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after digging in and messing with this a bit more, I found that the  (column in the row) also had to be overridden for the height setting.